# Integration (Redux with react native)

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using redux in `react-native` app. I fetched all values of the category from API & want to pass categoryId to the action.js file.
But I have an issue with passing fetched data to the action.js page. Anyone can give me a solid example of redux for getting data from API and pass it to action#flatlist and #redux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381621/adding-redux-to-an-existing-react-app/43381949#43381949

Answer (score 0):

You need to use redux-saga or redux-thunk to handle this scenario.
You can find examples here
[Redu-saga](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-redux-saga-example)
[Redux-thunk](https://medium.com/react-native-training/redux-4-ways-95a130da0cdc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need redux-thunk to handler promises you can use async/await and after your promise is solved you can dispatch new data;

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.fetchItems = this.fetchItems.bind(this);
  }

  async fetchItems() {
    const response = await api('api/items');
    this.props.dispatch('items', response.data);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => dispatch;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```