# How to render React Component with data from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new for the redux, I'm trying to implement a small concept in my react app.
I have received the data from dispatch and its in subscribe. How to print subscribe data to the UI. The below code is not working, where is the mistake and how to resolve it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export default class App1 extends Component {

  render() {

    const initalState={items:
                       [{
                             name:"test"
                       }]
                      };

    // Create Reducer, this is need state and action
    const reducer = function(state,action){
        if(action.type==='POST'){
            return action.payload;
        }
        return state;
    }

    // Create store, this is  need reducer and state
    const store=createStore(reducer,initalState);

    // Subscribe 
    store.subscribe(()=>{
        items: store.getState().items;
    });

    // Dispatch
    store.dispatch({
        type:"POST",
        payload:{
            items:
        [{
        name:"test 1"
    },
    {
        name:"test 2"
    }]
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
             {this.props.items.map((item) => <p> {item.name} </p> )}
        </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've change a little bit your code and created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nmfn0q5/365/) for better understanding.

In short, as you use **class** you should dispatch action within *componentDidMount* or some event, not *render* method. Secondly, I used `this.forceUpdate();` to rerender component after state has been changed.

I think you messed up a little bit **class based components** with **function based components**.

Here is full working sample and working jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8nmfn0q5/365/):

```
const initalState={
    items: [{
      name:"test"
    }]
};

// Create Reducer, this is need state and action
const reducer = function(state,action){
    if(action.type==='POST'){
        return action.payload;
    }
    return state;
}
// Create store, this is  need reducer and state
const store=Redux.createStore(reducer,initalState);

class App1 extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
       // subscribe
        store.subscribe(()=>{
            this.forceUpdate(); // actually triggers component to rerender on subscribe. Note you can also use this.setState() to trigger changes
        });

      // Dispatch
        store.dispatch({
            type:"POST",
            payload: {
              items: [
                {
                  name:"test 1"
                }, 
                {
                    name:"test 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
  }

  render() {    
    return (
        store.getState().items.length > 0 &&
        <div>
             {store.getState().items.map((item) => <p> {item.name} </p> )}
        </div>
    )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App1 />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: glad to hear, if this answer fits you and resolves your problem consider to accept it

Comment: How can I dispatch API data for this case

Comment: Maybe this can help you for API scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381621/adding-redux-to-an-existing-react-app/43381949#43381949